Azure DevOps ARM deployment pipeline task failing. Error: BadRequest: Creating or updating a system managed identity credential is not supported
The following yaml script fails with ARM Deployment task.
The error is quite strange because I am not updating a system with managed identity, but that is error.
The script is as follows:
- task: AzureResourceManagerTemplateDeployment@3
  inputs:
    deploymentScope: 'Resource Group'
    azureResourceManagerConnection: 'NewAzureConnection'
    subscriptionId: '8bxxxx28c1-4xxxc-axx-9xxxxx03'
    action: 'Create Or Update Resource Group'
    resourceGroupName: '$(ResourceGroupUAT)'
    location: '$(Location)'
    templateLocation: 'Linked artifact'
    csmFile: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/adf-xxx-fabric-dev/ARMTemplateForFactory.json'
    csmParametersFile: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/adf-xxxx-fabric-dev/ARMTemplateParametersForFactory.json'
    overrideParameters: '-factoryName $(DataFactoryUAT)'
    deploymentMode: 'Incremental'


Any thoughts on the error?
As mentioned by Vinicius, I believe the issue is with JSON file. I will provide a link to the full JSON file, in the meantime the code in the JSON that refers to ManagedIdentity looks like the following:
{
            "name": "[concat(parameters('factoryName'), '/WorkspaceSystemIdentity')]",
            "type": "Microsoft.DataFactory/factories/credentials",
            "apiVersion": "2018-06-01",
            "properties": {
                "type": "ManagedIdentity",
                "typeProperties": {}
            },
            "dependsOn": []

Should I change the managed identity?

Can you also add the JSON files? It seems that it is trying to update Managed Identity

@ViniciusDeschamps, I think we're on the same page with regard to the cause of the issue. I have updated the question. I think the full code would be too long to post here

I fixed the issue by commenting out the ARMTemplateForFactory.json that referenced the Managed Identity:
// {
        //  "name": "[concat(parameters('factoryName'), '/WorkspaceSystemIdentity')]",
        //  "type": "Microsoft.DataFactory/factories/credentials",
        //  "apiVersion": "2018-06-01",
        //  "properties": {
        //      "type": "ManagedIdentity",
        //      "typeProperties": {}
        //  },
        //  "dependsOn": []
        // },


Glad to hear that you have resolved the issue by commenting out the ARMTemplateForFactory.json that referenced the Managed Identity. Maybe you can also check the data Factory where the template is published to find where you used the system managed identity credential.
